# Changing Double Quotes to Single

Tags: ruby, quotes

I'm working on a project in Ruby. The library I'm using returns a string in double quotes, for example: `"\x00\x40"`. Since the string is in double quotes, any hex that can be converted to an ASCII character is converted. Therefore, when I print, I actually see: `"\x00@"`.

I figured out that, if I use single quotes, then the string will print in pure hex (without conversion), which is what I want. How do I change a double quoted string to single quoted?

I do not have any way to change the return type in the library since it is a C extension, and I can't figure out where the value is being returned from. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: this applies to string **litterals**, meaning strings found in your source code. Once parsed by the ruby engine, all strings are equal, therefore your problem seems weird. If you want to return escape sequences, you can also escape the anti-slashes in your double-quoted strings.

Comment: Escaping the backslash works, but I can't see any way to do this with returned data.

Comment: Well, please improve your question, because right now it's not precise enough to be clearly understood. Some code would probably help, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"\x00\x40"` and `'\x00\x40'` produce totally different strings.

`"\x00\x40"` creates a 2 byte string with hex values `0x00` and `0x40`:

```
"\x00\x40".length
# => 2

"\x00\x40".chars.to_a
# => ["\u0000", "@"]
```

`'\x00\x40'` creates a string with 8 characters:

```
'\x00\x40'.length
# => 8

'\x00\x40'.chars.to_a
# => ["\\", "x", "0", "0", "\\", "x", "4", "0"]
```

This is done by Ruby's parser and you cannot change it once the string is created.

However, you can *convert* the string to get its hexadecimal representation.

[`String#unpack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-unpack) decodes the string as a hex string, i.e. it returns the hex value of each byte as a string:

```
hex = "\x00\x40".unpack("H*")[0]
# => "0040"
```

[`String#gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) adds/inserts `\x` every 2 bytes:

```
hex.gsub(/../) { |s| '\x' + s }
# => "\\x00\\x40"
```

Comment: Excellent answer! My question is - how do you achieve here? :) Really feel proud. I never thought such difference till I have seen this answer.